# Node js array not getting updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi this is my function i am calling this from my controller like this:
  `var getLastPoll = await socketModel. getPollOptionsByPollId(data.poll_id);`
but i am getting empty array as result in controller but when i logged result in my model it is returning the data of array containing two objects ? where i am doing mistake can someone help?

````
const getPollOptionsByPollId = async (poll_id) => 
{
    var querySql1 = "SELECT * FROM public.group_poll_options 

                     WHERE option_poll_id= $1 AND 

                    option_status = $2 ORDER BY option_id";

    var queryParams1 = [poll_id, "active"];
    var pollOptions = await db.query(querySql1, queryParams1);
    var result = [];
    if (pollOptions.rowCount != 0) {


        pollOptions.rows.map(async value => {
            var voteCount = await totalvotesbypolloption(poll_id, value.option_id);
            console.log("voteCount",voteCount);
            var data = {
                option_id: value.option_id,
                option_poll_id: value.option_poll_id,
                option_value: value.option_value,
                option_status: value.option_status,
                option_created_at: value.option_created_at,
                option_votes: voteCount
            }

            result.push(data);
        });

    }
    return result;
}```
````

Comment: (Tangential, but why use `map` only to `push` the data into an array? That seems redundant.)

Comment: @DaveNewton hi map is used because i want to count the option_votes for each option any other solution ?

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes its input and creates a new array of the output. The only thing your usage does is populate `data` and push it into `result`--this is redundant; `result = pollOptions.rows.map(... => { /* the rest */ return data })` would do the same thing. If you throw away the result of `map` then `forEach` would be more idiomatic (and incrementally less wasteful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `async/await` when iterating over arrays with `map`, `forEach`, etc,  doesn't do what you expect it to do. All iterations will finish before `totalvotesbypolloption` is called even once.

Replace `map` with with `for...of`:

```
    for (const value of pollOptions.rows) {
        var voteCount = await totalvotesbypolloption(poll_id, value.option_id);
        console.log("voteCount",voteCount);
        var data = {
            option_id: value.option_id,
            option_poll_id: value.option_poll_id,
            option_value: value.option_value,
            option_status: value.option_status,
            option_created_at: value.option_created_at,
            option_votes: voteCount
        }

        result.push(data);
    }
```